# bootstrap 3 and search-query class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

This code is for bootstrap2.
**what is The equivalent of this html code in bootstrap3?**

`<div class="input-append pull-left visible-desktop" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                <input type="text" data-i-search-input="true" class="search-query" name="word" value="word" data-autocomplete="true" data-autocomplete-url ="" placeholder="Enter word" >
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
            </div>`

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Bootstrap 3 docs: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

```
<div class="visible-lg">
<div class="input-group" style="margin-top: 5px;">
    <input type="text" data-i-search-input="true" class="form-control" name="word" value="word" data-autocomplete="true" data-autocomplete-url="" placeholder="Enter word">
    <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/91940

'search-query' is gone.

Comment: by default this 'form-control' break line and takes 100% of width :( this suck